# SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000 java Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql

Este error me salta cuando intento insertar datos a una tabla usuarios la cual tiene un campo que está relacionado con una tala tipos, pero este fallo solo me da desde mi código java, cuando inserto desde DataGrip o PhpMyAdmin todo funciona bien.

Construí la relación de esta manera

```
ALTER TABLE `usuarios` ADD CONSTRAINT `usuariosTipos_fk0` 
FOREIGN KEY (`tipo_id`) REFERENCES `tipos`(`id_tipo`);
```

[image: Esta es mi tabla usuario]

[image: Esta es mi tabla tipos]

No para de decirme

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`dwproyecto`.`usuarios`, CONSTRAINT `usuariosTipos_fk0` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`tipo_id`) REFERENCES `tipos` (`id_tipo`))

No entiendo bien como puedo solucionarlo ayuda por favor 
Adjunto el modelo / entidad de mi tabla tipo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_usuario")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "clave")
    private String clave;

    @Column(name = "tipo_id")
    private int tipoId;
}
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que el dato que se inserta en tu FK no coincide con el dato con el que tiene en la tabla a la que referencia, podrías mirar a ver que datos tienen tus variables al llegar al insert y ver si estos coinciden con valores actuales de la tabla a la que referencia?

Answer (score 0):

Dicho error ocurre por lo siguiente:

- No puedes agregar el registro en una tabla en cuya estructura tiene una columna que es o depende de una tabla extra y que ese registro aún no existe.
- Al momento de crear un registro, la columna que es o sea clave foránea ya debe existir en la tabla principal que dentro de tu ejemplo sería: `tipos` apuntando a su columna `id_tipo`
- Probablemente a nivel de tu gestor de bases de datos *MySQL* esta desactivada la verificación de integridad y por dicha razón te permite llevar a cabo esas queries
- Algunos frameworks backend, traen en su configuración para interactuar con la base de datos la verificación de integridad, lo cual pudiera ser la razón que en dicho lugar no funcionen tus consultas y a nivel del gestor si

Verifica a nivel de la consola de tu gestor de bases de datos, con el siguiente comando que se active y verifique la integridad entre la columna padre 
*`(PRIMARY KEY)`* y la columna hija *`(FOREIGN KEY)`*

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHEKCS = 1;
```

A nivel de código si estoy haciendo esto:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios(id_usuario, nombre, clave, tipo_id)
VALUES
(1, "unUsuario", "mi-clave", 1);
```

Ese `1` que esta en la última posición apuntando a la columna `tipo_id` indica que existe un registro en la tabla `tipos` con `id_tipo` 1 y que lo usaremos para vincular ambas tablas en ese renglón.

Por lo tanto antes de hacer el alta anterior, yo ya debería contar con lo siguiente hecho:

```
INSERT INTO tipos(id_tipo, tipo)
VALUES
(1, "unTipo");
```

Entonces con el anterior registro ya existe y podemos usar ese `1` en la tabla `usuarios`